# Python: Assigning grouped mean to 1-D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose that I have 2 arrays:

```
x    = [2, 4, 1, 7, 3, 9, 2, 5, 5, 1]
flag = [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2]
```

The `flag` array indicates which "group" each element of `x` belongs to. How can I replace each element of `x` (with, say, flag value `k`) by the mean of all elements of `x` whose corresponding `flag` value is also `k`?

After such a transformation, `x` would look like:

```
x    = [3.25, 5.33, 3.25, 3.33, 5.33, 5.33, 3.33, 3.25, 3.25, 3.33]
```

(I could use loops to achieve this, but that would be quite inefficient.)

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I'm using NumPy to define these

Comment: So use the [numpy] tag next time. Lists and stdlib arrays and numpy arrays are all different, and for your question it matters. Your [MCVE] should contain arrays too to make this obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
x    = [2, 4, 1, 7, 3, 9, 2, 5, 5, 1]
flag = [0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2]
s = pd.Series(x,index=flag)
s.groupby(level=0).transform('mean').tolist()
```

Output:

```
[3.25,
 5.333333333333333,
 3.25,
 3.3333333333333335,
 5.333333333333333,
 5.333333333333333,
 3.3333333333333335,
 3.25,
 3.25,
 3.3333333333333335]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to compute grouped means:

```
import numpy as np
x    = np.array([2, 4, 1, 7, 3, 9, 2, 5, 5, 1])
flag = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 2])
total = np.bincount(flag, weights=x)
count = np.bincount(flag)
means = (total/count)[flag]
```

yields

```
array([ 3.25      ,  5.33333333,  3.25      ,  3.33333333,  5.33333333,
        5.33333333,  3.33333333,  3.25      ,  3.25      ,  3.33333333])
```

---

For more generalized grouped statistics there is also the [`scipy.stats.binned_statistic`  function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html). It can compute grouped mean, median, count, sum, min, max statistics. It can also accept user-defined functions for the statistic, but the performance will (of course) be slower than for the built-in statistics.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> def grouped_mean(data, flags):
...     flag_set = set(flags)
...     flags = np.asarray(flags)
...     data = np.array(data)
...     for s in flag_set:
...         m = (flags == s)
...         data[m] = np.mean(data[m])
...     return data
... 

>>> grouped_mean(x, flag)
array([ 3.25      ,  5.33333333,  3.25      ,  3.33333333,  5.33333333,
        5.33333333,  3.33333333,  3.25      ,  3.25      ,  3.33333333])
```